# AWS Dynamo DB supports embedded documents or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was following a lecture in which it says `Difference between DynamoDb and Mongo is that DynamoDB does not support embedded documents` So i thought something like this

```
Item: {
        "Artist":"No One You Know",
        "SongTitle":"Call Me Today",
        "AlbumTitle":"Somewhat Famous",
        "Year": 2015,
        "Price": 2.14,
        "Genre": "Country",
        "Tags": {
            "Composers": [
                  "Smith",
                  "Jones",
                  "Davis"
            ],
            "LengthInSeconds": 214
        }
    }
```

Will be an invalid item , but its valid input and it works [source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JsShell.03.html)

While trying to find out i ended up [here](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2014/10/document-model-dynamodb.html)  which says json nesting is valid.

The question is, is lecture wrong or am i missing something here like difference between nesting and embedding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that nested json is valid in dynamoDB. You will even be able to parse nested json nicely when querying it.

However it's not modeled as real nested object in mongodb (see Nested Sets in mongodb).

Comment: for simple question , does dynamo db support embeded documents or not ?   what u vl answer , looking from certification perspective

Comment: to make it short, yes nested json is valid, but this is different from nested document. GOOD TO KNOW for your certification: if you have such a question in your certification then you should answer that it does NOT support nested documents (trust me, I have several AWS certifications).